# How many times can a human get chicken pox?

Tags: pathology

How many times can a human get chicken pox?
For example: I got chicken pox, and recovered. If I was infected with HIV, and I am exposed to chicken pox again, can it infect me second time?, According to what I've heard, chicken pox comes only one time, because of the immune system of humans. But if I am infected with HIV and so definitely have immune system damage, will chicken pox come a second time, or will the immune system still protect the body from chicken pox?

Comment: after INFECTED with HIV,i am guessing shingles will come instead of chicken pox. but i have a doubt in this.

Comment: Suggestion: I think this question would be more useful for future reference if rephrased along the lines of: Can immunocompromised individuals be infected multiple times by diseases that you normally only get once in your life?

Answer (score 4):

Usually you get [chicken pox](http://www.cdc.gov/vaccines/pubs/pinkbook/varicella.html) only once in your life, the recurring form are usually shingles.  But: It can happen (also in people which are not immunocompromized). I know two persons which got chicken pox twice and which are otherwise normal in regards of their immune system.

Persons with an HIV infection are more at risk here. They can develop both forms and depending on how much their immune system is already affected by the HIV infection can develop severe forms of the infection. It might be necessary to treat them with antiviral drugs. So it is clearly recommended to ask a MD about this. See [here](http://hivinsite.ucsf.edu/insite?page=kb-00&doc=kb-05-03-01) for more details.